# Check multiple values in array using array_intersect

Tags: php

I have this two arrays & two methods. $inputArray can be either only[1,2]  or it can be[1,2,3,4].

```
$inputArray = [1,2];
$inputArray = [1,2,3,4];
$mainArray=[1,2,3,4,6,7,9];

$testObj->method1();

$testObj->method2();
```

Now need to execute method 1 only when there is no [1,2] in array.

I tried something like this but it fails for $inputArray.

```
if( count( $mainArray ) == count( array_intersect( $mainArray, $inputArray ) ) ) {
    $testObj->method1();
} else {
    $testObj->method2();
}
```

This is pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Try `in_array()` function:

```
if(!in_array("1", $inputArray) && !in_array("2", $inputArray)) {
  $testObj->method1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How ever you question is confusing like
1. when you say you want to execute the `method1` executed only when there is no [1,2] in array. so are you just point to specific 1 and 2 or count of 2 because 1 and 2 is also in the second array [1,2,3,4]

so in my mind as you are saying 3,4 is not in your desired array so i think below code will help you

```
<?php
    $inputArray = [1,2];
    //$inputArray = [1,2,3,4];  // uncomment the line and check your condition 
     $mainArray=[1,2,3,4,6,7,9];

   // as in your desired array 3 and 4 is not so just check for that you can 
   // also use the condition like `in_array('3', $inputArray) || in_array('4', $inputArray)
   if( in_array('3', $inputArray) ) {
        echo "<br />Method 2";

   } else {
       echo "<br />Method 1";

   }
  ?>
```

I hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is always `false`. [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) returns an array that contains the elements that are common to all its arguments. The result cannot be the largest array provided as argument. It is the smallest one or a subset of it.

The condition:

```
count(array_intersect($mainArray, $inputArray)) == count($inputArray)
```

is `true` when all the elements of `$inputArray` are present in `$mainArray`.

```
count(array_intersect($mainArray, $inputArray)) > 0
```

is `true` when at least one element of `$inputArray` is present in `$mainArray`. Of course,

```
count(array_intersect($mainArray, $inputArray)) == 0
```

when no element of `$inputArray` is present in `$mainArray`.

Use the one that matches your needs.